# Go mock function from extenal lib without interface

Tags: unit-testing, go, interface, mocking

I’ve used the following logger [lib](https://github.com/go-logr/logr) for our program.
We have create unit tests and we need to provide mock for version `0.4.0`
https://github.com/go-logr/logr/blob/v0.4.0/logr.go#L148

This is how we mocked the functions which works as expected

```
type testLog struct {
    msg   string
    key   string
    value string
}

func (log *testLog) Enabled() bool {
    return true
}

func (log *testLog) Info(msg string, keysAndValues ...interface{}) {
    log.msg = msg
    log.key = keysAndValues[0].(string)
    log.value = keysAndValues[1].(string)
}

func (log *testLog) Error(err error, msg string, keysAndValues ...interface{}) {
}

func (log *testLog) V(level int) logr.Logger {
    return &testLog{}
}

func (log *testLog) WithValues(keysAndValues ...interface{}) logr.Logger {
    return &testLog{}
}

func (log *testLog) WithName(name string) logr.Logger {
    return &testLog{}
}
```

Now we need to upgrade to version `1.2.0`
And the implementation is changed, **there is no interface**.
My question is how should I mock the logger with the new version ?

See this link with the followed functions
https://github.com/go-logr/logr/blob/v1.2.2/logr.go#L230

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for help in implementation

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how should I mock the logger with the new version ?

You cannot. Come up with a non mock-based testing strategy.

Comment: There is no solution for such case? so I cannot use it for testing as before?

Comment: @Alberto There are solutions but non is based on mocking. If you want to test that you will have to make the output of the logging actions inspectable. This could happen by providing your own implementation (forcing you to add the now missing interface yourself) or persisting the logs somewhere and inspecting them after writing. Options are manyfold but please just stop this mocking business: It is not a suitable testing strategy in Go.

Comment: Thanks, Not sure I got what does it mean to create interface myself? if there is any example/ref for such case it will be great, do you mean interface that include all the method above?